# Anaconda not updating to latest

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The latest version of anaconda is 2.5. When I type:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

I get

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda:
#
conda                     4.0.5                    py27_0
```

and

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda:
#
anaconda                  2.3.0                np19py27_0
```

respectively.

How do I get conda to get version 2.5?

- Running on 64-bit Windows 7
- Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (32-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this:

https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-25-release-now-mkl-optimizations

Instead:

```
conda update conda
conda install anaconda=2.5
```