# Anaconda Update - UNDESIRED Revert to Earlier Version

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I am running anaconda on OS 10.11.6.  I am not certain of the precise anaconda version that I previously had, but it was about 4-6 months old, I believe, and it was running Python 2.7.11.  I wanted to update both python (to 2.7.12) and anaconda (while I was at it) and so I used the standard procedure of

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

This has worked swimmingly for me in the past.  This time, however, it is taking me back to an earlier version of python (2.7.10) when I do this.  From running `conda --version` I see that I have conda 4.1.11, which is the latest, as I understand it.  However, when I run `conda update anaconda` I get a display saying:

```
anaconda                  2.3.0                np19py27_0
```

Similarly, with `python --version` I get:

```
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)
```

In my folder `~/anaconda/bin/` (which folder I also have in my PATH such that calls to python direct here) I have an alias named `python` which says that it was just updated today (which is when I ran the conda update, etc.).  But, it just points to a file `python 2.7` which is ins `~/anaconda/` and hasn't been modified since May 2015.

I figure if I did a complete uninstall and reinstall of anaconda, I could presumably clear this up.  I'd rather avoid that if possible though, since it would mean reinstalling all the rest of my other python packages, etc.

I also saw this SO Post: [Anaconda not updating to latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063923/anaconda-not-updating-to-latest) .  but when I try:

```
conda install anaconda=4.1.1
```

I get the following error:

```
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ....

The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda 4.1.1*
  - gevent-websocket -> gevent 0.13.7|0.13.8|1.0|1.0.1|1.0.2|1.1.0
  - gevent-websocket -> python 2.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

---

**Update:** I ended up just wiping my old installation and installing a fresh version of Anaconda.  It was a bit of a pain but it seemed like it would be less work than trying to track down what was happening with this bug.  Still though, I'd be delighted in any solutions people have to this issue for future reference by me and others who encounter this.

Comment: `Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.` - Did you do that? Can you add the results to your question?

Comment: @cel Thank you!  Yes, I did do that.  the output that I got was 16,000 lines long, so I wasn't certain what to do with that.  I was also a bit surprised, since I would have thought that anaconda would be automatically handling the dependencies.  Even the dependencies under various listings of anaconda 4.1.1 are about 560 lines long.  What in particular should I be looking for in those, and why would they just suddenly become an issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell. If you think this is an issue of the dependency resolver, you may want to file a bug at the conda repository at github.

Comment: @cel Ok, good suggestion, I will follow up along those lines.  Thanks!

Comment: I've had a similar problem and tried to uninstall various packages. I first removed the handful of packages I'd installed with pip (listed with `<pip>` using `conda list`), then `spyder-app`, `spyder`, `gevent`, `binstar`, `anaconda-client`, `ipython`, `node-webkit`, `ipython_genutils`, `scipy`, `numpy`, `mingw`. This was really just trial and error... It still wouldn't work until I finally removed `vs2008_runtime` (and then it even tried to upgrade to Python 3, although I managed to cancel and prevent that)...

Comment: ... It worked eventually, and I'm not sure whether removing those previous packages was necessary. I also guess `vs2008_runtime` isn't really an issue for you, since you're not talking about a Windows installation.

Comment: @Bruno Interesting.  Thanks for the info - it could come in handy in the future!