# Anaconda version update not working (Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Just tried to update conda via Anaconda Prompt but it is not working.
After I managed to open Anaconda Prompt as administrator to mitigate:The current user does not have write permissions to a required path. problem even if I open promt from navigator-Enviroments-base root - open terminal
after command `conda update conda`.

So After opening Prompt as Administrator I used commands from conda cheatlist from here:https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html
**I have updated Anaconda but when I ask version number it the same before updating.**

I typed: `conda update conda`
I got:

```
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
(Many packages here)
done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Program Files\Anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - conda

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
(packages)
The following packages will be UPDATED:
(packages)
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
(packages)

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: \ DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'D:\Program Files\Anaconda', env_name: 'None', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe", args are ['"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\cwp.py"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\python.exe"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py"', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'D:\Program Files\Anaconda', env_name: 'None', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe", args are ['"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\cwp.py"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\python.exe"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py"', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
- DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'D:\Program Files\Anaconda', env_name: 'None', mode: 'system', used_mode: 'system'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is "D:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe", args are ['"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\cwp.py"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\python.exe"', '"D:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py"', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
done
```

**And than I check version again ... and nothing!**

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>`conda --version`
conda 4.9.2

I used command in cheatlist:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update -n base conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Package Plan 

  environment location: D:\Program Files\Anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - conda

The following packages will be downloaded:
(packages)
Proceed ([y]/n)?


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

**I tied to check conda version again - and got the same old version I have before update**

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda -V
conda 4.9.2

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -V
Python 3.7.7

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list anaconda$
packages in environment at D:\Program Files\Anaconda:

Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : D:\Program Files\Anaconda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\G703\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\G703\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : D:\Program Files\Anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\Program Files\Anaconda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\G703\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\G703\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs
                          C:\Users\G703\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\G703\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.7.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

The same in Anaconda Power Shell:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda update -n base conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda update anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : D:\Program Files\Anaconda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\G703\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\G703\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : D:\Program Files\Anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : D:\Program Files\Anaconda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\G703\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\G703\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : D:\Program Files\Anaconda\envs
                          C:\Users\G703\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\G703\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.7.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

**Any ideas what I should try to properly update Anaconda and Navigator from the prompt?
Or I have to download New Version from the website and Uninstall old one?
Many Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to run:

```
conda update conda
conda install anaconda=<version>
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063923/anaconda-not-updating-to-latest) question.

Comment: Thx for trying to help but I want to Update Anconda version as whole. I can do it in several commands but why is it so hard.
As far as I understand the command ``` conda update -n base ```
must do the job - but it won't helps.
I think that's the point when everything broke apart.

Comment: And if  the 4.9.2 is up to date than why python 3.7?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can specify the python version when creating an environment. `conda create -n env_name python=3.9`

Comment: I found that webpage with the current anaconda version:https://www.anaconda.com/blog/individual-edition-2020-11 . I hope they could create the constant web page with the actual anaconda realease to know what version to upgrade.
So command `` conda install anaconda=2020.11 ``` must help. 
Thank you!